# Bulk collect in Oracle running slow

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, bulkinsert, query-performance

I am trying to load 90k data from source table with some manipulations in target table .I have created a procedure that uses `BULK COLLECT` with `LIMIT` but whenever I  execute that it throws:

> ORA-02395: exceeded call limit on IO usage
>  
>   ORA-06512: at "INSERT_EXTRACT_TABLE", line 46
>  
>   ORA-06512: at line 1
>  
>   02395. 00000 -  "exceeded call limit on IO usage"
>  
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

My code is

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE insert_extract_table(
    v_array_size IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 100)
IS
  i pls_integer;
type array
IS
  TABLE OF MISCDH_MIG_PARTY_LIST%ROWTYPE;
  v_data ARRAY;
  CURSOR v_cur
  IS
    SELECT  p1 AS ORIG_PARTY_ID,
      p2  AS ORIG_PARTY_NUMBER,
      p3    AS ORIG_PARTY_NAME,
      l_id,
      l_rel_code ,
      s_id,
      s_rel_code,
      CASE
        WHEN l_rel_code='PARTENT'
        THEN P1
        WHEN l_rel_code='CHILD'
        THEN
          (SELECT p1
          FROM Mapping B
          WHERE B.s_rel_code='PARENT'
          AND B.s_id        =a.s_id
          )
    END MIG_PARTY_ID,
    CASE
      WHEN l_rel_code  ='PARENT'
      OR s_rel_code='PARENT'
      THEN 'A'
      WHEN l_rel_code     ='CHILD'
      AND s_rel_code IS NULL
      THEN 'M'
    END MIG_STATUS,
    NULL                  AS MIG_STATUS_DESC,
    'MA' AS CREATED_BY,
    sysdate               AS CREATION_DATE,
    'MA' AS LAST_UPDATED_BY,
    sysdate               AS LAST_UPDATE_DATE
  FROM Mapping a;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH V_CUR bulk collect into V_DATA limit V_ARRAY_SIZE;
    FORALL i IN v_data.first ..v_data.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    insert into MISCDH_MIG_PARTY_LIST values V_DATA(I);
    commit;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  close V_CUR;
END insert_extract_table;
```

I am using Oracle 11g .Can anyone provide me tips how can I tune this code?

Comment: Looks like your DBA has set limits for the profile you are using when running this query. Try with smaller v_array_size, but also, in your case with only 90k rows, you might want to consider a simple INSERT ... SELECT ...

Comment: Thanks TenG for your comments.I tried with Array-size of 100 ,inserts 2.8k after that same error.Tried simple Insert ..Select , same error.

Comment: Just to be cleart, By simple INSERT .. SELECT I mean do not use the bulk collect. You should ask your DBA to investigate the resource limits for your prrofile.#